# EFS file access problems

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

in my organization, i have a deadline to deploy **EFS** using AD CS, and i am working with a **single** windows **server 2003** box, which is the Root CA, and is the same server responsible to certificate enrollment.
All configuration, enrollment, issuance etc. works well, except, after creating a file and  encrypting it, *only the file creator and the recovery agent can access that file*. others get an "Access Denied" error, ***even after adding their certificate to the file***.

I have recreated the same scenario over and over again using a virtual environment(vmware) and it **works perfectly**, 
But when i apply the same steps in the real server, all works except the part where other users get the "Access Denied" error when trying to access files encrypted.

Am i doing something wrong? what could be the possible reason for this?
**please if you need any detail, ask me**. thanks